# Wordpress custom text widget html support

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-widgets

I have a custom text widget but I cant write html code in it.
Is there any way to add html support to custom widget?

Note: I know there is Wordpress Text Widget but I have to use this custom widget.

Here is my code: https://codepaste.net/ct4yee

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is calling **strip_tags()** which removes HTML tags. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php.

Comment: What a mistake! Thank you so much, I am appreciate for your help :)